# Using Paperclip with FFmpeg and multiple output formats: how to store in the database and show in the view a specific output format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, paperclip, codec, video-conversion

Because I want to use HTML5 video [I need to convert videos uploaded by the user into multiple codecs](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html). I am following this tutorial: http://jimneath.org/2008/06/03/converting-videos-with-rails-converting-the-video/ but it only outputs FLV, a format I don't even want at all.

I know I can add more FFmpeg commands and convert multiple times, but the problem lies in the database and the view. How can I define multiple `source_file_name`s in the DB, and how can I specify in `@video.source.url` which format I want? Should I subclass the `Video` model, add more table columns for each type or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Paperclip allows you to specify multiple styles. Generally, this is used to specify multiple sizes for uploaded images; Paperclip processes the image once for each style and places them in the filesystem accordingly. By specifying different video formats for your styles and subclassing `Paperclip::Processor`, you can create your own video formats. In your model, you'd do something like this:

```
has_attached_file :video, :styles => { :mpeg, :ogg, :wmv }, :processors => [:my_custom_processor]
```

And then create a custom Processor that runs the correct FFmpeg command based on each style. See the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.3.8/Paperclip/Processor) for more info, but here is a snippet:

> Paperclip processors allow you to
>   modify attached files when they are
>   attached in any way you are able.
>   Paperclip itself uses command-line
>   programs for its included Thumbnail
>   processor, but custom processors are
>   not required to follow suit.
>
> Processors are required to be defined
>   inside the Paperclip module and are
>   also required to be a subclass of
>   Paperclip::Processor. There is only
>   one method you must implement to
>   properly be a subclass: #make, but #initialize
>   may also be of use. Both methods accept 3 arguments: the file
>   that will be operated on (which is an
>   instance of File), a hash of options
>   that were defined in
>   has_attached_file’s style hash, and
>   the Paperclip::Attachment itself.
>
> All #make needs to return is an
>   instance of File (Tempfile is
>   acceptable) which contains the results
>   of the processing.
>
> See Paperclip.run for more
>   information about using command-line
>   utilities from within Processors.

When you create a link to a Paperclip attachment, you pass the style to determine which to link to:

```
<%= link_to "mpeg video", @model.video.url(:mpeg) %>
<%= link_to "ogg video", @model.video.url(:ogg) %>
```

Comment: Just figured it out. You can write interpolations to generate the extension based on the style...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you tryout [paperclip-ffmpeg](http://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg) gem.